# Material UI How can i get meunItem key and value when touch up

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

material ui how can i get MenuItem's key and value when touch up.

the code snippet like below:

```
<Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to='/'>
    <MenuItem key='somekey' value='somevalue' onTouchTap={this.menuItemTap}>my menu item </MenuItem>
</Link>
```

// func:

```
menuItemTap = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    // this.props.highlightMenuItem(event.key)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In material ui components you need to pass multiple arguments and in menuItem second value is considered as value so you need to pass second argument as

```
onTouchTap={(evt,somekey) =>this.menuItemTap(somekey)}
```

and now get it as

```
menuItemTap(somekey)
{
console.log(somekey)
}
```

make sure that arguments vary in case of different components like in SelectField component third argument is considered as name.so you can go through the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
onTouchTap={(event) => this.menuItemTap(event, somekey)}
```

and your function to

```
menuItemTap = (event, key) => {
    console.log(event);
    this.props.highlightMenuItem(key)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just pass an object which contains the Key as a value

```
<Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to='/'>
    <MenuItem key='somekey' value={{value: 'someValue', key: 'someKey'}} onTouchTap={this.menuItemTap}>my menu item </MenuItem>
</Link>
```